# Infopath Check boxes

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form that I want the user to be able to check a checkbox and depending on who or how many they check a workflow starts and sends those appropriate people an email.

So Like so:

Person 1 :
Person 2 :
Person 3:

So, if I choose Person 1 and 3 Emails will be generated and sent to 1 and 3.

I tried to use the Multiple checkbox control but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the actual format of your email addresses "Person 1: Person 2: Person 3:"?  Is Person x a person's name or an email address?

If it's a name, use the email address instead.  Also, the approved separator for email addresses is not :.  You will want to use a comma (,) I believe.  If that does not work, separate them with a semicolon (;) and you should be OK.  You may want to use a hidden field with some rules if that doesn't work with just the normal functionality of the check-boxes.

Comment: Well no what I want is a list of checkboxes and the user can check with person(s) they want to send the email to. So if there are 5 people they want to send the email they can check those 5. Click submit and on it goes.

Comment: Alright, but then you should at least be using the email address as the value of the checkbox, while displaying the person's name as the label.  The checkboxgroup control may have an option for which character is used to concatenate all the selected options - make sure it is valid for email addresses.